# Do I put my (mostly) static website in the public/ folder or index.js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a single page application that I recently rewrote in React using create-react-app, because I use one complex React-Bootstrap component. The rest of my website is simple html/css/images.

Currently, I put these in the `public/` folder, and both the new component and the static `index.html` reference some of these files. However, I am wondering whether I should be putting my CSS, JS, image, and/or HTML files in the `src/index.js` file instead, in order to take advantage of React's minifying/bundling features?

I initially adopted React only because of the one complex component, but now I imagine it could be better to put any CSS and images used into `src/`. However, it seems counter-intuitive to put all of the `index.html` contents into React, since they never change, and thus it would be a waste to render that content using React.

Any thoughts are much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static content that will always definitely exist, there isn't any benefit to putting static content into the React code instead of into the HTML. The React code may be minified, but the HTML code will be gzipped too, at least if it's being served from any sane server.

Also, a benefit of putting static content into the HTML is that the page will show that static content *immediately* on page load, without having to wait for the React script to download and parse.

Comment: What about common CSS used by the react app? Is there any benefit to adding that to src?

Comment: Depends. Critical CSS for the basic layout of the overall site and container can be inlined so that it takes effect immediately. Other CSS that only takes effect when the component is rendered can be wherever you want, but I'd prefer to put it in the React app so that you can (1) take advantage of preprocessors like SCSS (2) separate concerns; make it explicit which components are tied to which CSS, for greater reusability.